# TypeError: srcObject is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, video-streaming

good day everyone! hope you guys have a good day! i'm working on my webcam video project, using video, i've some obstacle, didn't know why, but this pretty annoying,

I have `<video>` wrap with ref, looks like this

```
<div className="">
   <video className="h-52 w-full" ref={userVideo} />
</div>
```

and this is my const `ref`

```
const userVideo = useRef();
```

then, in my `useEffect`, i want to put `mediaDevices.getUserMedia` inside ref

```
 navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
  .then((stream) => {
    console.log(stream);
    userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
```

and why i got this `error`?

```
TypeError: userVideo.current is undefined
```

I'm using `NextJS` for this project, please someone help :(

/* EDIT */

here's my `code`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function page() {
  const userVideo = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        console.log(stream);
        userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
      });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <video className="h-52 w-full" ref={userVideo} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `userVideo.current` to your useEffect's watch list like this:
`useEffect(()=>{
    if(userVideo?.current){ navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then((stream) => { console.log(stream); userVideo.current.srcObject = stream; }}, [userVideo?.current]);`

Comment: From where have you imported that `Video` component ? Is it from a library or made by you ? Or is just the native html tag of `video` ?

Comment: Hello @MohammedMaaz thanks for your reply, i do, didn't do anything, just blank, seems the logic didn't work

Comment: Hello @LakshyaThakur thanks for your reply, i'm sorry, typo, it just `<video>`

Comment: Can you post the entire code where `userVideo.current` might be getting used ?

Comment: Did the error disappear after adding to the useEffect's watchlist?

Comment: Yeaaa i can, here's the code @LakshyaThakur https://imgur.com/a/FXS08UZ

Comment: Yaa, the error is disappear, but i got blank page.. @MohammedMaaz

Comment: @HaksatryaBhaswara Try calling `play` on the video element after setting the `srcObject`, e.g., `userVideo.current.play()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
userVideo.current.srcObject = stream
```

to this:

```
userVideo.srcObject = stream
```

Comment: Hello Ozzo, thanks for your reply, i try it tho, but didn't work..